# Changing color in jQuery in if condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have written a code to change the CSS (color font) of tr, but it's not working. If I remove the condition and use `$(this).css("color","white");` then it works perfectly. But when I do this in if condition it fails to change the text color. What am I doing wrong with this one? Thanks.

```
$('tr').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('hilite');          
        //$(this).css("color","white");
        if($(this).css("color") == "black"){
            alert("In first if");
            $(this).css("color","white");
        }else{$(this).css("color","black");}
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect if you look at the return value of `$(this).css("color")` (e.g., [in a debugger](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html)), you'll find that it's not "black" but instead "rgb(0,0,0)" or similar. (You can [see it here](http://jsbin.com/ereke3) — I get "rgb(0, 0, 0)" in Chrome, probably many other browsers as well.) You'll need to handle that, either by keeping track of the colors (or perhaps based on your "hilite" [sic] class) or by parsing the result.

The best thing, of course, is to have your "hilite" class control the text and background color, so you don't have to do it in your JavaScript at all. E.g., with this rule:

```
tr.hilite, tr.hilite td, tr.hilite th {
  background-color: black; /* Or whatever your dark background color is */
  color: white;
}
```

---

**Off-topic**: *Every time* you call `$()`, there are multiple function calls and a memory allocation involved, so if you're going to do that several times in a row, it's best to grab the result and reuse it.

```
$('tr').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);               // Grab it once
    $this.toggleClass('hilite');       // Use it throughout
    //$this.css("color","white");
    if($this.css("color") == "black"){ // (You'll still need to fix this)
        alert("In first if");
        $this.css("color","white");
    }else{$this.css("color","black");}
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks it worked by just adding a css class :). I haven't seen yet with the if condition but i will try this also by debugging either i am getting the correct color value which i am giving is "black". Again thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Sydenam: Yeah, sadly these things are not consistent. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Make use of classes instead of dealing with `.css` calls. You can easily check if an element has a class by calling `.hasClass('foo')`.

Maybe that is what the 'hilite' class is for? If so, you can change to this:

```
$('tr').click(function () {          
    if($(this).hasClass("hilite")){
        alert("In first if");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('hilite');
});
```